# Java: Store a list of files as a variable

Tags: java

Im trying to use Java to store a list of files in a directory as a variable.

Basically I want to know how to do the following python commands in Java

```
os.chdir("<directory>")
list = os.listdir(".")
```

I know its a really simple question but Java really confuses me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29):

```
File[] filesInDir = new File("<directory>").listFiles();
```

Comment: This guy is "confused by Java". You should really make sure your syntax is correct. (You're missing the `();` at the end of your statement.)

Comment: thanks, as a side note what program do you recommend to write programs in? I'm using BlueJ, just wondering if you can recommend any others that are easier to use/understand

Comment: @user2148423 I use eclipse IDE

Comment: @user2148423 I work with Eclipse and NetBeans, but my favorite is Eclipse. Some people say BlueJ is better, but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `File#listFiles`.

Not being fluent in Python, I'm not sure whether you mean that you want the returned array to contain files only or both files and subdirectories.

If you need to filter out the directories, it's easily done through the use of a `FileFilter`:

```
File[] list = new File(".").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isFile();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick [google search](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/3-java-program-can-list-all-files-given-directory.html) I've found this:

```
import java.io.File;

public class ListFiles 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
{

  // Directory path here
  String path = "."; 

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
  {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
   {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
   System.out.println(files);
      }
  }
}
}
```

That should work.